# CSS media queries not working in Safari

Tags: css

Does anyone know why media queries not working in Safari? For example:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:860px) {
    body {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color:orange;
    }
}
```

This example(http://jsfiddle.net/crUVv/show) works great in all browsers except in Safari.

Comment: are you talking about safari for mobile or safari desktop? and which version exactly?

Comment: Desktop version(Windows, V5.1.7)

Answer (score 1):

use this `meta` in your `head`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
</html>
```