# Css media queries not works in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, media-queries

Attention: Possible duplicated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941530/css-media-queries-not-working-in-safari) (and I found more answers with the same solution) but it does not solve my problem.

Hello, I want to change color of some element when size of screen is different, here is my CSS rules they will told you all I hope:

```
#my_div {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #08c5ef;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    #my_div {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #my_div {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

It works in all browsers except Safari(5.1.7), the line always green. Can somebody help me? Maybe I wrote wrong media queries?

Comment: please add demo link to better understand your media syntax is perfect

Comment: did you try specifying both min-width and max-width range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such mediatype as "only", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

Safari(5.1.7) is quite old now, we are up to 8.0.5

this is 1 possible explaination

Comment: I testin on Windows, and if I do not confuse anly 5.1.7 available for Windows. So you want to say that I should remove `only` from query deffinition? or what? I am newbie in design.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove "only" from your tag. I am keen to know what the problem was if you have solved it