# Why doesn't position: fixed add a footer on every page in print preview using media print css in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

I have added below footer css using a media query . It's working fine on every browser except Safari.

```
@media print {
footer{
       position:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        display:block;
}

}
```

Please help me . Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media queries not working in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941530/css-media-queries-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Not sure this is a dupe @gpgekko - this is an issue specific to Safari when showing position: fixed elements in print - rather than the media query part (i.e. the same issue is reproducible when using a discrete file for print CSS (I think)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to stretch you body in viewport by 
body { height: 100%; } || body { height:100vh; }

Furthermore you are in @print media configuration, so this won't work on screen replace || remove it

Comment: It's not working. When I changed position:absolute then footer is coming  on the last page.

Comment: Can share you code here as snipped? Then we can help